# Firefox not showing AJAX requests from a content script in the "Network" tab

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox-addon

I'm trying to build my first webextension, but having some troubles regarding web requests. When I do an AJAX request (or, indeed, any request at all), it doesn't show up in the "Network" tab.

I'm looking at both the network tab of the application, and the network tab in the addon debug window.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/sellitem/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            // data here
        },
        crossDomain: true,
        xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
    }).done(function (data) {
        // handler here
    }).fail(function (jqxhr) {
        // handler here
    });
```

I can see the request ends in 400 if I hit a breakpoint in "fail" branch and inspect the jqxhr variable, but I would really like to be able to compare the requests in the network tab to find out what goes wrong.

Edit 1: My permissions in the manifest.json:

```
"permissions": [
        "*://steamcommunity.com/market/*",
        "webRequest"
    ],
```

Comment: Seems like ajax fails even before sending request, hence your browser does not shows up ajax request in the network tab

Comment: I think this is very possible, I had to add "webRequest" to permissions to even see at least 400 - Bad request, even though I didn't see this permission as required in the other addon (and it seems to work just fine). I have added the permissions to my question.

Comment: From which context is your request triggered from? browser action popup, background script, content script? That might help us.

Comment: The request is made from the content script.

Comment: use async xmlhttprequest, it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made some tests with requests triggered from a `browser_action` popup, and the requests did not show when I used the "Debug" console from "about:debugging" page.

[image: Addon debugging ui]

I'm not sure why, if this is on purpose or a bug, just like you I'd expect the network calls to be logged into the debugging console.

---

However, I managed to see the requests made from my addon popup by opening the overall **browser toolbox**, which is not bound to your specific extension (that means you'll also see output from other addons).

You can open it through `Tools > Web developer > Browser toolbox` menu. And there, you can see the request triggered from the extension:

[image: Browser toolbox - Network tab]

---

*Note: the [issue 1410357 on bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1410357) seems to be related to this behaviour*

Comment: Thank you, it does indeed appear in the browser toolbox. This is pretty cumbersome, but this will have to do for now I guess.

Also, thanks for commenting on the bugzilla issue, maybe this will get it more awareness :)

Comment: This a workaround indeed, but for now, it seems to be the only solution available. But I was just as surprised as you when I noticed this. This behaviour doesn't seem the most logical one, as far as I'm concerned.